# Can't get call / message from A7 gsm+gprs+gps module

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, gps, uart

I am making a project using arduino uno & A7 gsm+gps+gprs module.my circuit connection is like this:

```
A7 UTXD -> arduino RX
A7 RTXD -> arduino TX
A7 GND -> arduino GND
A7 pwr_key -> A7 VCC5.0
```

When i make call from my mobile to A7,it's ok.But i cannot get call/msg from A7.
Here is my code for making call:

```
char phone_no[]="phone_no";

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);  
delay(200);
Serial.println("AT");
delay(1000);
Serial.print("ATD");
Serial.println(phone_no);
//Serial.println(";");
delay(10000);
Serial.println("ATH");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

What can i do now??? Please help me to fix it.I apologize for my poor english.

Comment: What is the output returned from your ATD command? Any debug messages, errors, etc?

Comment: Don't use `delay()` like that. Instead you need to actively parse the returned text from the modem to understand what is happening with it.

Answer (score -1):

Increase your second delay to 2000 (ie. 2 seconds).

```
delay(2000);
```

Comment: Why? How that solve the problem? You just give a number, not an explanation.

Comment: Using delays in place of proper serial processing is not good advice. Increasing delays to try and combat a basic failing of the entire methodology is even worse advice.